# Why to create new dataframe to filter? On Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to pandas, I was just practicing some examples (code pasted below), I need a clarification, I read the csv file, I have applied change of value on 'age' & 'survived'
based multi conditioned filter on the data frame one on each line;

when I print the original data frame after the two lines I have both the new values applied on the data frame.

But when I tried to filter the existing data frame I had to assign it to an new data frame object to see the changes?, why is that? can someone pls explain the behavior?
when i tried to do any manipulation on that new data frame it shows

"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame" warning,
yet the change is applied!

I do not understand.. Can someone pls help me with the concept and what is the right way to do it?.
Thanks in advance guys!!

```
import pandas as pd

tit_read = pd.read_csv('titanic.csv').head(10)

tit_read.loc[(tit_read['pclass'] > 1) & (tit_read['sex'] == 'male'), 'age'] = 50

tit_read.loc[(tit_read['age'] > 35) & (tit_read['sex'] == 'male'), 'survived'] = 2

print(tit_read)

#2nd data frame

df = tit_read.loc[(tit_read['pclass'] > 1) & (tit_read['sex'] == 'male')]

df.survived = 3

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the `"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"` is due to the difference between operations returning `views` or `copies`.

A `view` as the name suggests is only similar to looking at the DataFrame through a filtered window, or put in a technical way it is a subset of the DataFrame which is still linked to the original DataFrame. Whereas , a copy is an entirely new DataFrame.

A point to note is that, since the views are still linked to the original DataFrame, whatever changes you make to the view are reflected in the original DataFrame. This does not happen with copies as they are completely different entities.